# transition-property: background-blend-mode ignores transition-duration

Tags: css

Hover the Top Left `h1` element on [this code example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GPV59FUNA5DH)

It will change the `h1` element to blue-ish nicely within 2 seconds.

It will not change the blend mode of the backgrounds within the defined transition duration. While it will apply the hover rule and change blend mode, it will ignore the transition duration.

How can I apply transition duration to the blend mode as well?
It seems to be ignored!

Comment: `background-blend-mode` is a non animatable property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot animate `background-blend-mode`. As a workaround, you can use a div, with same background image, and `background-blend-mode: soft-light, normal;` as default.
On hover, you can change `opacity` to 0, revealing body's background image, which has `overlay` blending mode as default.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, viewport-fit=cover" />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.humanofearth.com/" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <style>
        body,
        div {
            min-height: 100vh;
            min-width: 100vw;
            color: red;
            background-color: black;
            background-image: url("https://www.humanofearth.com/img/humanofearth-bkg-no-bkg.png"), url("https://www.humanofearth.com/img/universe-bkg.webp");
            background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed, fixed;
            background-size: contain, cover;
            background-position: center left, center center;
            background-blend-mode: overlay, normal;
            transition-property: color;
            transition-duration: 2s;

        }

        body:hover {
            color: blue;
        }

        div {
            background-blend-mode: soft-light, normal;
            opacity: 1;
            transition: opacity 2s;
            z-index: -1;

        }

        div:hover {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <title>HumanOfEarth</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>HumanOfEarth</h1>
    <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation and example, makes sense and resolves the issue.